# How can I assign a program/window to a workspace any time I start it - GNOME 18.04?

Tags: 18.04, gnome-shell, workspaces, window, window-management

On Unity I had Compiz Config. It was responsible for my workspace grid, and with it I could make specific type of window appear in specific workspace.

So terminator was always on row 2 column 4, emacs row 1 column 4. Chrome row 3 column 2, Libre office writer row 4 column 2, Texworks row 4 column 4... Etc.

How is it possible in Ubuntu 18.04? Can I do it with gnome shell extensions? Is it possible to install Compiz Config and make it work like old times without switching to Unity? Do I have to switch to Unity for this?

I just upgraded from 16.04 to 18.04 and I'm trying to make it work.

Comment: I *think* i found it, as "Auto Move Windows" Gnome shell extension, need to test it and maybe post it as answer.